# AD authentication / authoraztion + WAM

Tags: authentication, web-application

soon we are going to introduce the OTRS Ticketing system in our environment - it will be used to handle security incidents related to SAP. Agents will be using their AD id's + pwd to authenticate (only users belonging to certain AD groups will be permitted to access the system and depending on the group membership they will get appropriate roles assigned and this in turn will limit what they can see and do within the application) -this is the functionality that the application provides by itself. Now, there are talks to make the system available via a WAM (Web Access Management) but I fail to understand what added value it would bring ? Is in it somehow complicating the overall setup (unnecessary) or is there a valid point of using it?

Thank for any input!

Comment: anyone? any comments are more than welcome!